# spring boot DefaultPointcutAdvisor not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

when i use the advisor api to implements aop log like this, but it does not work.
it's advisor config class.

```
@Configuration
public class AspectAutoConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultPointcutAdvisor myLogAnnotation() {
        DefaultPointcutAdvisor myLogAdvisor = new DefaultPointcutAdvisor();
        myLogAdvisor.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 500);
        AnnotationMatchingPointcut myLogAnnotationPointCut =
                new AnnotationMatchingPointcut(MyLog.class, true);
        MethodLogInterceptor logInterceptor = new MethodLogInterceptor();
        myLogAdvisor.setPointcut(myLogAnnotationPointCut);
        myLogAdvisor.setAdvice(logInterceptor);
        return myLogAdvisor;
    }
}
```

it's the interceptor class.

```
public class MethodLogInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("methodName = " + invocation.getMethod().getName()
                + " , arg[] = " + Arrays.toString(invocation.getArguments()));
        try {
            return invocation.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finish invoke " + invocation.getMethod().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

it's the application class.

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@SpringBootApplication
public class AspectApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AspectApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

the pom.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

but it does not work, can anlyone help me. thanks.
the github sample is https://github.com/luolibing/coding-life/tree/master/spring-boot-sample/spring-boot-aspect-api

Comment: Why would you like to do this in the way you are doing? IMHO, there are better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
AnnotationMatchingPointcut myLogAnnotationPointCut = new AnnotationMatchingPointcut(MyLog.class, true);
```

the first parameter should be class annotation or null
like

```
new AnnotationMatchingPointcut(Service.class,MyLog.class, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it easy using spring aop flavor with annotation

1: you already enable  @EnableAspectJAutoProxy

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
    class Application {
    //main class
    }
```

You just create your custom aspect logic

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomAspect  {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(cn.tim.aspect.api.annotation.MyLog)")
    public void target() {};

@Before("target()")
public void before() {
//do what you want
}
}
```

you can you @Around, @Before @After and more as per your requirement 
here is [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api)

Also here is some [example of it in github](https://github.com/techguy-bhushan/Pas/tree/master/src/main/java/com/playwithspring/part1/chapter4/aop/annotation)

Comment: the way of Aspect annotation, i know. but i want try api